# Using ng-hide based on previous element in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How do I use `ng-hide` based on the previous select dropdown? I would like to show `#additional-option` if option C is selected in the dropdown.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3">Option:
        <span class="required">
            *
        </span>
    </label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option selected>A</option>
            <option>B</option>
            <option>C</option>
            <option>D</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>  

<!-- Show the below only if C is selected -->
<div class="form-group" id="additional-option">
    <label class="control-label col-md-3"></label>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label>
            <div class="checker">
                <span>
                    <input type="checkbox">
                </span>
            </div>
            Additional option
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You bind the view controls to scope items and check the values in other bindings. So in your case you can bind your first select to scope as below.

`ng-model="formData.selectedLetter"`

Then you can use `ng-show` in the next control to check the value for the previous select control.

`ng-show="formData.selectedLetter === 'C'"`

You could also use `ng-hide` if you must, by reversing the condition expression.

This will ensure that the second control is only visible if the `formData.selectedLetter` is 'C'.

Comment: It works but for some reason the select defaults to some empty option which is not even in the list. How do I fix this?

Comment: You need to initialize the model. The "how" depends on the way you defined the options (there are several alternatives). I suggest you take a look at the `select` directive in Angular's docs. See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/b4czA/)**.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to setup a two-way binding on your  element like so

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="selectedOption">
```

and use that value in the ng-show directive for the div that needs to be hidden, like so

```
<div ng-show="selectedOption === 'C'" class="form-group" id="additional-option">
```

here's the plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/XsXs4uhNTB6cKAL4IM5f?p=preview